# Opera Input Doesn't POST

Tags: javascript, post, input, opera

I have created a script which posts data to a page automatically.  It can be found below:

```
echo '
    <html>
    <body onLoad="javascript: document.process.submit();">

    <form method="post" action="pagehere.php" name="process">
';

foreach($post_data as $k => $v) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='$k' value='$v' />";
}

echo '
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
';
```

It works as intended in all other browsers apart from Opera (testing on version 11.50).  The `<form action>` attribute works and the user is redirected to the new page.  However, the hidden input fields are not sent to the new page.

I have tried removing the JS and replacing it with a standard submit button, with no luck.  I have also tried using standard `<input type="text">` tags just to test, and again, have had no luck.  Oh, and no luck submitting with jQuery either, although that again was fine with IE/FF.

Am I missing something stupid, or is this a very strange problem?

Thanks.

Comment: *"It can be found below:"* No it can't. Doesn't even appear in the source view, so it's not just a formatting problem (though there *was* a formatting problem; I've fixed it). So...can you post the script? Remember to format it correctly (see **How to Format** on the right when you're editing).

Comment: Your script seems to have gone missing - any chance you could re-post it?

Comment: My mistake, sorry.  Was in a hurry to get the post up and I forgot to C+P it in. Thanks :)

Comment: Try outputting double quotes instead of single ones. One way to do that is by escaping: `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$k\" value=\"$v\" />";`

Comment: I'm familiar with character escaping!  But thanks for the reply.  I have tried both single and double quotes; neither make a difference.

Comment: I doubt it would make a difference, but you have /> ending your hidden inputs, and > ending your submit input. There should be no reason to mix the styles like this - you either have HTML or XHTML, and that should determine how you end the tag.

Comment: I missed that!  Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, it doesn't make a difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching the internet, it turned out I was looking at the wrong thing completely.  The proxy settings in Opera were not configured correctly for my development environment...

Thanks to everybody who took the trouble to read/answer.